# ¿Cómo tener un formulario con options de guía sin que se envíen a la base de datos?

Tags: laravel, formularios

Tengo un formulario que contiene la opción de seleccionar carreras, pero este campo es opcional puede quedar vació, y tengo un option que dice "Seleccionar carrera", sin embargo si no se selecciona ninguna carrera marca un error que prácticamente es que la columna "seleccionar carrera" no se encuentra registrada en la base de datos. Esto claro por que no existe este campo ya que solo es para darle una ayuda al usuario de lo que debe hacer.

```
    <div class="from-group">

        <label for="careers_id">Carrera asociada al grupo:</label>

        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name="careers_id" id="careers_id">
            <option selected>Seleccione una carrera</option>
            @foreach ($careers as $career)
                <option value="{{ $career->id }}">{{ $career->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        @error('careers_id')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
```

En mi validación:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
        'code'       =>  'required|string',
        'careers_id' =>  '',
    ];
}
```

Comment: No entendi bien el problema tu options de Carrera no quieres que pase la validacion o que no se guarde en la bd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no está recibiendo valor la variable careers_id, ponle el valor 0 en tu option

```
<option value="0" selected>Seleccione una carrera</option>
```

en la validación ponle integer.

Ya cuando vayas a meter a la base de datos haces un if career_id!=0 metes el valor o no.